# "$(...).validate is not a function" even if i directly placed the jquery.validate.js codes in head

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js">         </script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.15.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#signupform").validate({
            rules:{
                email: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 10
                },
                password: {
                    required: true
                },
                password2: {
                    equalTo: "#password"
                }
            },
            messages: {
                email: "test"
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Above is my code for calling the validate method i placed in .
It keeps on saying $(...).validate is not a function.

Then, i removed this:

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.15.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>
```

and i directly placed the js codes i get by visiting "http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.15.0/jquery.validate.js" into the head inside a `<script></script>`,
which the validate method is supposed to be must be existing now,
however, i still get $(...).validate is not a function.

Anyone know what is causing the problem in here?

Comment: Try to put the code outside `$(document).ready(function () {})`

Comment: What output do you get in console if you do `console.log( $("#signupform").length )`?

Comment: Make sure you are not including 2 different versions of `jQuery` on the same page. Also, make sure that `jQuery` is using the `$` variable, and its not another javascript framework.

Comment: What you posted **cannot** cause this error. The code is correct, the issue is not reproducible. Either update the question with demo/complete code or you can close the question, nothing to answer here.

Comment: include HTml code in description

Comment: Try using include your `js` library locally , and after that initialize the validate function.

Comment: download the validate.js and try it. https://jqueryvalidation.org/

Comment: if you check the developer tools, can you see the files being downloaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you so much for your comments.

After spending some hours i finally find the cause of this problem:
There is sitemesh applied that automatically add a jquery script link at the BOTTOM of body, making the resulted page having 2 jquerys added to it, while there is no way i can find out this wicked extra jquery added by just looking at the codes in the IDE.

Comment: If that's the case you can use `jQuery.noConflict()` in your code and avoid conflicts with other versions of jquery loaded later. https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/